# How to process raster maps to get the same number of rows and columns?

Tags: qgis, raster

For modeling purposes, I need to use two raster maps that contain exactly the same number of rows and columns. How should I process my maps to obtain this result? For now, my maps don't have the same number of rows and columns...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that they are aligned with the same resolution (cell size), in QGIS you can do that with this approach. For example, I have these 2 raster maps where it is obvious that I should clip the big one by the small map:

[image]

First, open layer properties of the "small" map and copy its extent in a text editor (see next image, red rectangle). Modify the order 1, 2, 3, 4, without commas, to 1, 4, 3, 2 and copy it.

[image]

Close layer properties and open Clipper Tool in **Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper**. Select the names of input and output files, and drag with the mouse one arbitrary area on the map and click on the icon pencil for editing **gdal_translate** command. Change **projwin** parameters for the modified at text editor.

[image]

After OK, the clipped image it will have the same number of rows and columns if they have the same resolution.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to work this around in R? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231165/same-extent-and-resolution-of-rasters-but-different-number-of-cells